# Heap vs stack-allocated node objects in singly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm currently trying to implement data structures from scratch as a way to better understand how they work while learning C++ and how to use raw pointers at the same time, and right now I'm working on a singly linked list:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node* next;
};

template <typename T>
class SLL {
private:
    Node<T>* m_head;
    Node<T>* m_tail;
    std::size_t m_size;
public:
    explicit SLL(std::vector<T>& values);
    Node<T>* get(int index);
    void insert(int index, T value);
    void print();
    void set(int index, T value);
};

template<typename T>
SLL<T>::SLL(std::vector<T> &values) {
    m_size = values.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: {
                auto tmp0 = new Node<T>{values[0], nullptr};
                m_head = tmp0;
                m_tail = tmp0;
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                auto tmp1 = new Node<T>{values[1], nullptr};
                m_head->next = tmp1;
                m_tail = tmp1;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                auto tmpDefault = new Node<T>{values[i], nullptr};
                m_tail->next = tmpDefault;
                m_tail = tmpDefault;
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* SLL<T>::get(int index) {
    if (0 <= index < m_size) {
        int i = 0;
        Node<T>* tmp = m_head;
        while (i != index) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }
        return tmp;
    } else throw "Index out of bounds";
}

template<typename T>
void SLL<T>::insert(int index, T value) {
    Node<T>* prev = get(index - 1);
    Node<T>* next = prev->next;
    auto toInsert = new Node<T>{value, nullptr};
    toInsert->next = next;
    prev->next = toInsert;
}

template<typename T>
void SLL<T>::print() {
    Node<T>* tmp = m_head;
    while (tmp->next != nullptr) {
        std::cout << tmp->value << " ";
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    std::cout << tmp->value << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void SLL<T>::set(int index, T value) {
    if (0 <= index < m_size) {
        int i = 0;
        Node<T>* tmp = m_head;
        while (i != index) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }
        tmp->value = value;
    } else throw "Index out of bounds";
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    SLL<int> sll(vec);
    sll.print();
    sll.insert(4, 1337);
    sll.print();
    Node<int>* node = sll.get(4);
    std::cout << node->value << std::endl;
    sll.set(6, 600);
    sll.print();
    return 0;
}
```

There are likely many issues with my code that I'm unaware of, so identifying them would be greatly appreciated.

However, my main question was about the behavior of my code when I instantiated the temp Nodes in the SLL constructor on the stack rather than the heap (I saw there was a problem with this and switched to heap instantiation, but I don't understand what's going on well enough to understand the problem), with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
SLL<T>::SLL(std::vector<T> &values) {
    m_size = values.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: {
//                auto tmp0 = new Node<T>{values[0], nullptr};
//                m_head = tmp0;
//                m_tail = tmp0;
                Node<T> tmp0{ values[0], nullptr };
                m_tail->next = &tmp0;
                m_tail = &tmp0;
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
//                auto tmp1 = new Node<T>{values[1], nullptr};
//                m_head->next = tmp1;
//                m_tail = tmp1;
                Node<T> tmp1{ values[1], nullptr };
                m_tail->next = &tmp1;
                m_tail = &tmp1;
                break;
            }
            default: {
//                auto tmpDefault = new Node<T>{values[i], nullptr};
//                m_tail->next = tmpDefault;
//                m_tail = tmpDefault;
                Node<T> tmpDefault{ values[i], nullptr };
                m_tail->next = &tmpDefault;
                m_tail = &tmpDefault;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When going through the debugger to figure out what was wrong with this, I saw that every time tmpDefault was instantiated after the first time (so for i = 3, 4, 5...) this would change the value of m_tail and m_tail->next, does this mean tmpDefault is instantiated in the same memory address each time? Also, if I understand correctly, tmpDefault is destroyed as soon as we leave the scope of the default case, so how come I don't see any change in the value of m_tail once I leave the scope in the debugger (shouldn't it be pointing to an unallocated block of memory resulting in value being equal to some random integer)? Thanks!

P.S. I'm not sure what would be a good, descriptive title for this post, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `m_tail = &tmp0;` ... `m_tail = &tmpDefault;` causes undefined behavior. `tmpDefault` no longer exists after you hit the first }. So you end up storing a pointer to a node that does not exist. This is called a dangling pointer.

Comment: Since you want a linked list where each created node remains allocated, you should not use the second way, as there the memory allocation is temporal until the variable is out of scope.

Comment: I LOVE automatic allocation. It makes life so much easier and usually executes faster. Unfortunately it's fairly difficult to make a linked list of automatically allocated nodes. You need to allocate the nodes ahead of time (usually in an array) and store them in another list, a "free list", you can get nodes from when necessary. When that list is empty, well... What you do when you're out of nodes is up to you. I do this all the time in embedded systems, but not so much on a PC where memory is cheap and plentiful.